AWS Cloudwatch Log Insights parsing with regex
I have a Cloudwatch Log with a value like:
SCTE35::splice_insert [SpliceInsertType=SpliceIn] [Clock=IngestM2TS] [PCR=09:42:19.031] [SpliceTimeBeforeAdjustment=09:42:19.065] [SpliceTime=09:42:19.065] [SplicePreroll=00:00:00.033] [Base64=/DAgAAAAAAAAAP/wDwUAAAPpf0/+u22BESnSAAAAABeAGh0=] [splice_event_id=0x000003E9] [pts_time=3144515857] [pts_adjustment=0] [auto_return=(-)] [duration=(-)]

Within Log Insights, I would like to parse the SpliceInsertType value and use it as a display. As an example I would like SpliceIn to be the only thing displayed on the Log output.
Here is my Log Insight:
filter message like "SpliceInsertType" | 
parse message /(?<=SpliceInsertType=)[^\[\]]+/ as splice_insert_type |
display splice_insert_type

What am I doing wrong? I have validated the regex and it seems fine.
